# How is this returning a value when it has not been defined?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to understand overloading operators, and I've been staring at this for longer than I want to admit. I believe that I understand everything in the class EXCEPT the operator+ member. I'm trying to teach myself with the plethora of information available, but I can't find any information that explains to me what I'm seeing here--and I'm a firm believer if I understand HOW something works then I can use it better.

So, mostly, my confusion lies with how the compiler knows which variable of temp to choose. (temp.x or temp.y) I realize main() is asking for c.x and c.y, but operator+ seems to be returning something that wasn't defined yet. There is no ternary operator or anything that would make it pick which one to return.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CVector {
public:
    int x,y;
    CVector () {};
    CVector (int,int);
    CVector operator + (CVector);
};

CVector::CVector (int a, int b) {
    x = a;
    y = b;
}

CVector CVector::operator+ (CVector param) {
    CVector temp;
    temp.x = x + param.x;
    temp.y = y + param.y;
    return (temp);
}

int main () {
    CVector a (3,1);
    CVector b (1,2);
    CVector c;
    c = a + b;
    cout << c.x << "," << c.y;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's not returning `temp.x` or `temp.y`, it's returning `temp`.

Comment: Right, I understand that. I'll rephrase. How is it returning temp? It doesn't appear to me that temp has a value to return yet. I anticipated that I would see something like:
    return (temp = x ? temp.x : temp.y);

Comment: How do you think it does not have a value?

Comment: Temp was initialized when you first called it.  You have an empty constructor which simply initializes the instance of the class *and its data members* (IE int x and int y) with no assigned values.  Then you assign each data member a value, and return a copy of the values in the instance of the class.

Comment: What do you mean temp doesn't (appear to) have a value?  You created it, and you assigned values to both of its members (x and y).

Comment: Sorry for the frustration guys. I understand that both values are initialized in the class but what I don't understand is how the compiler is returning both or one of those values. {} (from the default constructor) to me means that nothing was defined on what to return if a function asks for it. 
For example, why is it returning 4 for x and 3 for y after +b is called. I would think that it needs to link something first in the constructor. Some kind of condition that if sent one thing, send this back, else send that back.

Comment: The operator returns a `CVector`, not an `int`. C++ has no problem returning complex objects - it's not limited to just plain old datatypes.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Maybe this will explain a little bit more what I'm having trouble understanding. Sorry for the readability.

temp.x = x + param.x; //how does it know to pick this one when the c.x is couted.
temp.y = y + param.y; //how does it know to pick this one when the c.y is couted.
return (temp);
//Comparing this to an integer why can’t I std::cout << temp;

Comment: I think `operator+` may be a red herring.  What you really seem to be confused about is assignment (`operator=`).  Tell me, would you have the same confusion if the statement in `main` was simply this? `c = a;` -- rather than this? `c = a + b;`

Comment: Yes, just as confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, mostly, my confusion lies with how the compiler knows which
>   variable of temp to choose.

I really don't understand what you mean by this.  The compiler is not choosing a variable of temp to return.  `temp` is an object of type `CVector`.  It contains two data members, `x` and `y`.  These members exist as part of `temp` when it is created with this line:

```
CVector temp;
```

Then, when you do this:

```
return temp;
```

There is nothing for the compiler to choose.  It is returning the whole object, which includes both the `x` and the `y` in one compound object.

In your main function, this line:

```
c = a + b;
```

Calls `operator+` on `a` and `b`. Then the return value (`temp`) is assigned (`operator=`) to `c`.  Since you haven't defined a custom assignment operator, the default one kicks in, which simply does a memberwise assignment from `temp` to `c`.  So, `temp.x` is assigned to `c.x`, and `temp.y` is assigned to `c.y`.

For your class, the default assignment operator would look like (or have identical operational semantics to) this, if it were written out:

```
CVector & CVector::operator=(const CVector & rhs)
{
    this->x = rhs.x;
    this->y = rhs.y;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: This is very helpful, is there a syntax of what the default one looks like?

Comment: @Scott: There you go.

Comment: You're the man! Thanks a ton, I've spent countless hours today trying to understand this. Will vote this up once I get 15 rep.

Answer (score 1):

Realize the operator (+) is essentially just an instance method.

```
temp.x = x + param.x;
temp.y = y + param.y;
return (temp);
```

Here it is assigning the sum of the Instance value of 'x' and param.x.
Imagine it's called as:

```
CVector a (3,1);
CVector b (1,2);
CVector c;
c = a.+(b);
```