# Why do I need to make references constant when there are private variables?

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading

This is a bit of code from http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/92-overloading-the-arithmetic-operators/

I have been looking into operator overloading from several self-teaching websites and browsing forums. I asked a question about overloading using a different method and I understand that now. That Q&A link is here [How is this returning a value when it has not been defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19238086/how-is-this-returning-a-value-when-it-has-not-been-defined)

However, this method with references I do not understand. I have tried to play with different ways to implement the code and have seen that some ways work that are less complicated.

The way I understand to do this is make an instance of a class as a parameter of the operator function, a temporary instance inside the operator function and return those values with an = operator. This way is much more complex and I have a couple of issues as to why this even works.

The questions are worded as you go down the code but here are the three questions I have.
(Question 1) Ceteris parabis, why do I need the const keywords in the parameters? I know that if I make the variables public I don't but why if there is a friend class, or if the code is written inside the class itself do I need to use const.
(Question 2) If I put the friend function inside the class, I still need the keyword "friend" why?
(Question 3) Where are the classes c1, and c2 initialized? There is a reference for them, but there is no initialization until the return, but that is below the reference. I would think there would be an error when compiling.

```
class Cents
{
private:
    int m_nCents;

public:
    Cents(int nCents) { m_nCents = nCents; }
    //I know this assigns each
    //instance to the private variable m_nCents since it's private.

    // Add Cents + Cents 
    friend Cents operator+(const Cents &c1, const Cents &c2); 

    //why do we need
    //to make this a friend? why can't we just put it inside the class and not  
    //use the "friend" keyword? also why do I need to make the variables public
    //if i remove const from the parameters

    int GetCents() { return m_nCents; } 
    //I know how this is used to return the
    // variable stored in m_nCents, in this program it is for cout
};

// note: this function is not a member function!
Cents operator+(const Cents &c1, const Cents &c2)
//where are these references 
//actually defined? I do not see c1 or c2 anywhere except in the return, but
//that is below the code that is referencing the class
{
    // use the Cents constructor and operator+(int, int)
    return Cents(c1.m_nCents + c2.m_nCents);
}

int main()
{
    Cents cCents1(6);
    Cents cCents2(8);
    Cents cCentsSum = cCents1 + cCents2;
    std::cout << "I have " << cCentsSum .GetCents() << " cents." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe the following is more illustrative: When you calculate the sum, your code is equivalent to:

```
Cents cCentsSum = operator+(cCents1,cCents2);
```

(yes, the above is actual legal code as well).

This is more similar to a function call, which the operator in fact is. The references are the parameters, hence `const Cents& c1` references `cCents1` and `const Cents& c2` references `cCents2`.

This free function now needs to be implemented, but you are accessing `c1.m_cents`, which is `private`. In order to allow this, you need to declare the method a `friend`, otherwise the free function you wrote would yield an access error.

You *still* need to declare it a `friend` even if you put it inside the class because operators are special. The compiler sees that your operator + has **two** arguments, hence it knows that this is *not* a member function. It is actually equivalent to the code for the free function, just more compact.

Finally, you want those references to be `const` to avoid accidential modification. Consider if you write:

```
Cents operator+(Cents &c1, Cents &c2)
{
    return Cents(c1.m_nCents += c2.m_nCents);
}
```

Note the `+=` instead of `+`, it would modify the value of `c1`. In your example, this would mean that *after* you called

```
Cents cCentsSum = cCents1+cCents2;
```

the value of `cCents1` would have been modified. Certainly not desirable. By making the parameter const references, you ask the compiler to ensure that the above can't happen and is reported as an error when compiling the code.

Comment: This is very simple and helpful. I understand question 3 now. For question 1, I get the importance of const but my compiler, XCode, throws an error when I remove const keywords all other things remaining unchanged. Is that just because my compiler knows that the outcome could be disastrous so it decides to not compile it or is this something that would throw an error to any compiler?

Comment: @Scott have you removed `const` for both the `friend` declaration *and* the actual definition? They need to match, you can't remove `const` on just one of them.

Comment: @Scott I added one more paragraph to my answer to hopefully help you understand Q2.

Comment: I could have sworn I did, but it appears that I didn't. It's compiling when I do that. Sorry I should have double checked before I posted that part. Also your added explanation makes sense on the friend function. Many thanks!

Comment: There's an additional reason. Assume a `class Dollar` which will convert to 100 `Cents`. If you now call `Dollar(2) + Cents(3)`, the result will be `Cents(203)`. This only works if both arguments to `operator+` are `const&`. The converted value cannot be passed to a non-const ref. The reason is that the non-const ref might attempt to modify the temporary, which is generally unintended.

Comment: @MSalters True. Temporaries or explicitly `const` values as well, as in `const Cents cCents1(6);` in the OPs example. I left it out as the OP seemed confused enough (OP: no offense intended) by the topic already and I thought that less is more in this case. There will be more things like `int GetCents()` not being a `const` method, but that's material for the OPs next question. :)

Comment: @MSalters Thanks, when I go into more advanced writing I will refer to this.  
DanielFrey No offense taken, and I am sure another question will be on the way shortly. ;) Thanks so much for all your help, this forum is great.

Answer (score 3):

The big bonus to const is it means they wont change, because with C++ the compiler can see all the types, if it is not mutable but const it knows that only const methods can be called and such, ad it can enforce that const methods not alter that state (when compiling the implementation of those classes)

When you use a const anything the compiler can be sure that it will not change (unless mutable, lets ignore that though) so it can make some nifty optimisations to the code.

If every function argument is const and not mutable then the compiler knows when it uses those functions that the object is in the same state before and after the call, so any values in registers for example need not be refreshed (although register allocation comes much later).

Const is good, if someone is a "total const whore" that's a compliment.

So to answer the question, private means that only friends and the class can alter the state, const means no-one can (unless mutable).

It's hard to give an example because optimisations only occur when the compiler can PROVE that following the/a standard the resulting code goes though the exact same program states as if it did what you wrote.

```
class State {
private:
    bool state;
public:
    State() {
        state = false;
    }
    bool getState() {
        return state;
    }
    void alterState() {
        state = !state;
    }
};

void doSomething(State&);

int main(int,char**) {
    State state;
    bool before = state.getState();
    std::cout<<"The state is: "<<before<<"\n";
    doSomething(state);
    bool after = state.getState();
    std::cout<<"The state is: "<<after<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

And suppose doSomething is defined in another file.

When we find after the compiler must do a call to state.getState() as it cannot prove that before == after.

If however we have:

```
void doSomething(const State&);

int main(int,char**) {
    State state;
    bool before = state.getState();
    std::cout<<"The state is: "<<before<<"\n";
    doSomething(state);
    bool after = state.getState(); 
    /*compiler can do after=before because bool
     is a type that will produce the same result
      as if it actually did the getState*/
    std::cout<<"The state is: "<<after<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

This shows how const is great. The compiler knows that doSomething takes a constant (reference to a) State, and as state has no mutable fields it knows there's no way the State state could change because of that call. If they are all in the same file it may see what doSomething does (it doesn't change the state suppose) and realise it can do it anyway, modern ones are VERY very clever like that. You want to give the compiler every opportunity to optimise.

Passing about const references means everything can look but not touch, so any values the compiler has to hand are valid, because it's const they can't change.

Remember this:
All optimisations work as if they never happened at all, the program state is the same, without a stop-watch or a debugger or disassembler you cannot tell what the compiler has done. It may optimise out some variables (if it can **prove** that has no side-effects), printing that variable though will stop it doing that, the compiler will always do exactly what you type, as per the standard.

Comment: Amazing explanation as to why the compiler is requiring the const keyword. As far as the friend class, if I move the function inside the class so that it is a member why do I still need to include the friend word while variables are private? Is it because there are references inside that are initialized outside of the class?

Comment: @Scott not quite sure what that means, if you copy and paste a function into a class declaration it becomes a member.... you shouldn't need that, go to your question click edit put "__bonus round__" to make it bold and put an example or the problem there (incase that didn't work, to make something bold put two underscores before and after it)